# Data pipeline in tf.keras with tfrecords or numpy

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets, tf.keras, tensorflow2.0

I want to train a model in tf.keras of Tensorflow 2.0 with data that is bigger than my ram, but the tutorials only show examples with predefined datasets.

I followed this tutorial:

[Load Images with tf.data](https://www.tensorflow.org/alpha/tutorials/load_data/images#a_dataset_of_image_label_pairs), I could not make this work for data on numpy arrays or tfrecords.

This is an example with array being transformed into tensorflow datasets. What I want is to make this work for multiple numpy array files or multiple tfrecords files.

```
train_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((x_train, y_train))
# Shuffle and slice the dataset.
train_dataset = train_dataset.shuffle(buffer_size=1024).batch(64)

# Since the dataset already takes care of batching,
# we don't pass a `batch_size` argument.
model.fit(train_dataset, epochs=3)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have `tfrecords` files:

```
path = ['file1.tfrecords', 'file2.tfrecords', ..., 'fileN.tfrecords']
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.list_files(path, shuffle=True).repeat()
dataset = dataset.interleave(lambda filename: tf.data.TFRecordDataset(filename), cycle_length=len(path))
dataset = dataset.map(parse_function).batch()
```

parse_function handles decoding and any kind of augmentation.

In case with numpy arrays, you can construct dataset either from a list of filenames or from list of arrays. Labels are just a list. Or they could be taken from file while parsing single example.

```
path = #list of numpy arrays
```

or

```
path = os.listdir(path_to files)

dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((path, labels))
dataset = dataset.map(parse_function).batch()
```

parse_function handles decoding:

```
def parse_function(filename, label):  #Both filename and label will be passed if you provided both to from_tensor_slices
    f = tf.read_file(filename)
    image = tf.image.decode_image(f)) 
    image = tf.reshape(image, [H, W, C])
    label = label #or it could be extracted from, for example, filename, or from file itself 
    #do any augmentations here
    return image, label
```

To decode .npy files, the best way is to use `reshape` without `read_file` or `decode_raw`, but first load numpys with `np.load`:

```
paths = [np.load(i) for i in ["x1.npy", "x2.npy"]]
image = tf.reshape(filename, [2])
```

or try using `decode_raw`

```
f = tf.io.read_file(filename)
image = tf.io.decode_raw(f, tf.float32)
```

Then just pass batched dataset to `model.fit(dataset)`. TensorFlow 2.0 allows simple iteration over dataset. No need to use iterator. Even in later versions of 1.x API you could just pass dataset to `.fit` method

```
for example in dataset:
    func(example)
```

Comment: Let's say I passed filenames of numpy array files. What my parse_function should have to load those files?

Comment: Added info to answer

Comment: I used the parse_function but using numpy files, and the error was thrown when iterating through the dataset. 

InvalidArgumentError: assertion failed: [Unable to decode bytes as JPEG, PNG, GIF, or BMP]
  [[{{node Assert/Assert}}]]
  [[cond_gif]]
  [[cond_png]]
  [[decode_image/cond_jpeg]] [Op:IteratorGetNextSync]

[colab link](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1jgM2Suf-9XPRRqojANa6YKrQAHl7fSyI)

Comment: If this is .npy file , not image file, you may try to use decode_raw. But it may produce inconsistent result. Another way is just using reshape. Updated answer

Comment: Using [np.load(i) for i in ["x1.npy", "x2.npy" ...] with a lot of numpy files could use too much ram?